# Finding a Maclaurin Series for a non-elementary integral.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am self-studying from a calculus textbook and I have been working on this problem for days to no avail. I cannot find a similar problem on the internet anywhere. The problem is stated as such:

Find a Maclaurin series for $f(x)$. Hint: Use $$\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!(2n-1)}$$ for $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5\ldots (2n-3)$

$$
f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+t^7} \mathrm{d}t \\
f(x) = x+\frac{x^8}{16}+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \ldots
$$

So far what I have tried is:
expanding the function (of $t$), integrating term by term, and then solving the definite integral. However, this is where I am stuck and I cannot find a general equation for the series. I will reproduce my steps below in order to aid in the process, but I will leave out the algebra to find the expansion of $\sqrt{1+t^7}$.

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+t^7} \mathrm{d}t \\
&=\int_{0}^{x} \left( 1+\frac{t^7}{2}-\frac{t^{14}}{8}+\frac{t^{21}}{16}+\ldots \right)\mathrm{d}t\\
&= \left( t+\frac{t^8}{16}-\frac{t^{15}}{120}+\frac{t^{22}}{352}+\ldots \right)_{0}^{x}\\
&=x+\frac{x^8}{16}-\frac{x^{15}}{120}+\frac{x^{22}}{352}+\ldots\\
&= x+\frac{x^8}{16}+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \ldots ??
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hint:- By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+t^{7}}dt=\sqrt{1+x^{7}}$$

Comment: @RAHUL I might be a bit dense here, but doesn't this lead me to the same scenario? If I find a series for the function's derivative then I still must integrate term by term and I'm left with the same series.

Comment: @hvna No, it doesn't. We have a simple expression for the first derivative that we can easily take subsequent derivatives of. No need for integration.

Comment: YOu should add your answer (with details) as an actual answer rather than edit your original post!  Self answers are encouraged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay along with some very helpful comments, I found an answer finally!

So using the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$
f'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+t^7} \mathrm{d}t = \sqrt{1+x^7}
$$
Expanding the derivative of the function:
$$
\sqrt{1+x^7} = 1+\frac{x^7}{2}-\frac{x^{14}}{2!\cdot4}+\frac{3x^{21}}{3!\cdot8}-\ldots
$$
Then finding a general formula for $f'(x)$ and integrating we are left with:
$$
\frac{x^{7n+1}(-1)^{n+1}(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2(2n-1)(7n+1)}
$$
Finally:
$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+t^7} = x + \frac{x^8}{16} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{7n+1}(-1)^{n+1}(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2(2n-1)(7n+1)}
$$

Thanks for the help.